# How to change the WKInterfaceSeparator from horizontal to vertical?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard, apple-watch

I want to create a vertical separator like this:

[image]

However there isn't an option to rotate the WKInterfaceSeparator to vertical.

Comment: "Thanks" for the downvote without any explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this by using groups and changing their background color and set the radius.